# Mean term in simple linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, covariance

I am trying to derive the expression for the $E(y_i \epsilon_i)$  in simple linear regression.  I substitute using $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$, so $E(y_i \epsilon_i) = Cov(y_i , \epsilon_i)-  (E(y_i)E(\epsilon_i))$ and $E(\epsilon_i)=0$, so  $E(y_i \epsilon_i) = Cov(y_i , \epsilon_i)$, but I  don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: For $E(y_i\varepsilon_i)$, substitute the expression for $y_i$ and use linearity of expectation.